# Проблема с драйверами под жёсткий диск в kali linux

Tags: установка, драйвер, kali-linux

Всем доброго дня. Недавно решил установить kali linux на старенький нетбук, но вот не задача. Как только установщик доходит до дисков, то выводится следующие сообщение "Программа установки не обнаружила дисков. Если вы знаете имя драйвера, нужного для вашего
диска, то можете выбрать его из списка.". Я перепробовал все предложенные драйвера, а также решил поискать драйвера на сайте производителя, нашёл только под винду. Название диска => wd1600BEVT-22A23T0. Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте для начала поставить ubuntu или другой линукс для обычных пользователей. Если он не установится, тогда действительно проблема в ноутбуке и нужно пошаманить в биосе. Если же они установятся, тогда похоже проблема в Kali Linux. Но я сильно-сильно сомневаюсь, что проблема именно в драйверах на жесткий диск.

Comment: На данный нетбук я уже устанавливал дистрибутив lubuntu и всё работало отлично. Может мне стоит попробовать более старый дистрибутив kali.